# if you have a long signed array, can you break it up using wires?

Tags: verilog

Imagine for simplicity that I have a 50-bit input into my module.  This 50-bit input is split into ten 5-bit signed words.  Is this how you would make each part of the input signed?

```
module(in, out)
input signed [49:0] in;
wire signed [4:0] in_temp [0:9];
genvar i;

for(i = 0; i < 128; i = i+1)
assign in_temp[i] = in[5*(i+1)-1 -: 5];
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's one way. You can also cast each slice using `$signed(in[5*(i+1)-1 -: 5])`, then you don't need an intermediate signal.

SystemVerilog adds another option. You can defined a packed array which is a 50-bit vector made up of 10 signed 5-bit vectors.

```
typedef logic signed [4:0] int5_t;
typedef int_5_t signed [9:0] int50_t;
module m(input int_50_t in, output out));
// can now use in[1] as a 5-bit signed signal which corresponds to bits [9:5] of the 50-bit vector
```

Comment: Hi Dave, is this Verilog or System Verilog? I haven't seen this syntax before

Comment: `$signed` is Verilog-2001.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot! Do you know if there's a difference in Synthesis between the two methods? Would there be extra overhead my way?

Comment: Probably no difference. *Signedness* only effects certain arithmetic and relational operates. There's no hardware in continuous assignments.

Comment: Perfect.  That is my need.  I am doing signed addition/subtraction.

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter if you make the result signed or unsigned. once you split up a wire it losses its meaning.

For example: If you split up signed 8'b00011111 into two equal parts you get 4'b0001 and 4'b1111. What would be the 'value' of each of those 4 bit numbers? 
Only if you later concatenate them again in the right order do you get the original number back.

Answering you question:
It does not really matter but I would make all the individual parts unsigned as the top bit from all but one, is no longer a sign bit and as such the type can be confusing. You could be pedantic and make one signed and nine unsigned vectors.
What would be more useful is to use a name like `in_split` to indicate this is a part of a vector which has been split up.